# Hide/Show columns in Custom List based on dropdown selection

Tags: jquery, custom-form, cewp

I am trying to hide a column on page load and when a value is selected from a drop-down list, have the hidden dropdown appear. I am able to hide the column but when I choose the value in the drop-down, nothing happens.

This is the code I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


//Define which columns to show/hide by default

$("h3.ms-standardheader:contains('Project Subtype')").closest("tr").hide();

//Show/hide columns based on Drop Down Selection 

$("select[title='Project Type']").change(function() {
if ($("select[title='Project Type']").val() === "Photo") 
{ 
    $("h3.ms-standardheader:contains('Project Subtype')").closest("tr").show();
} 
else { 

    $("h3.ms-standardheader:contains('Project Subtype')").closest("tr").hide();
}  

 });
});
```

I've also tried to use this one with the same results:

```
$('nobr:contains("Project Subtype")').closest('tr').hide();
```

UPDATE: I've added alerts to try and filter out the issue and it seems like

```
$("select[title='Project Type']").change(function() {
```

seems to be the issue. But I have no idea why it's not being read.

Thank in advance for any ideas on this one!

Comment: I would rater use InfoPath with formatting rules to hide and show content

Comment: It would be a little easier to do it that way but because InfoPath is going to be phased out eventually, I'm trying to learn how to do it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it figured out. I had renamed the "Project Type" column, even though it changed in SharePoint, the ID didn't. To check that, I clicked F12 for the developer tools, searched "Photo Type" and found that the name was actually "Photo Type Required Field". Once I updated my code to reflect that, I was good to go!

Rookie mistake!

Thanks M.Qassas for all your help!

Answer (score 10):

Your code should be worked, Just one note If you are using SSL, so you should use the HTTPS JQuery reference.

**The below code should work**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('nobr:contains("Project Subtype")').closest('tr').hide();  
    //Show/hide columns based on Drop Down Selection 
   $("select[title='Project Type']").change(function() {
 if ($("select[title='Project Type']").val() != "Other") 
   {
     $('nobr:contains("Project Subtype")').closest('tr').hide();
   } 
 else 
   {
     $('nobr:contains("Project Subtype")').closest('tr').show();
   }
   });
});
</script>
```

**Output**

[image]

---

> **For more details, Please check**
>
> - [Show / Hide fields based on choice field selection using JQuery in
>   SharePoint.](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/show-hide-fields-based-on-choice-field-selection-using-jquery-in-sharepoint/)
> - [Show and hide fields based on a Choice field selection in ‘New Form’, ‘Edit Form’ and ‘Display Form’ in SharePoint 2013 / 2016 via SPUtility.js?](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/show-hide-fields-based-on-a-drop-down-using-sputility-js/)

Comment: I use : .parent().parent().parent().hide() and .parent().parent().parent().show(), but your approach looks a lot cleaner, i'm going to start using yours ;

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70068/discussion-on-answer-by-m-qassas-hide-show-columns-in-custom-list-based-on-dropd).

Comment: Check also **[Disable Choice Field in SharePoint Froms](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/read-only-choice-field-in-sharepoint/)**

Answer (score 0):

Had to change the code of "Mohamed El-Qassas" and use `text()` extension.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function () {
            $('nobr:contains("Other Project Type")').closest('tr').hide();
            $("select[title='Project Type']").change(function () {
            console.log("selection changed", $("[title='Project Type'] option:selected").text());
                if ($("[title='Project Type'] option:selected").text() != "Other") {
                    $('nobr:contains("Other Project Type")').closest('tr').hide();
                }
                else {
                    $('nobr:contains("Other Project Type")').closest('tr').show();
                }
            });
        });

</script>
```